# How can i format the excel report though php application

Tags: php, yii

How can i format the excel report though php application
I am able to generate the excel report in php but how can i do the formatting changes in the excel.

eg. I have to add image in excel.
    Red borders to columns.
    some background color to excel
    Change the font color

Help appriciated

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is directly possible without any libraries.

Have a look at [`PHPExcel`](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/), You will be able to do what you are looking for.

Credits to [`Mark Baker`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/324584/mark-baker).

### Tougher Way

You will need to generate XHTML from your Excel document, After that you need to search and parse for tags and do your formatting and stuff.